# How to specify during the run the Number of Features (Vector Type) in Kmeans Clustering with ML.Net

Tags: c#, .net, cluster-analysis, ml.net

I want to use the ML.Net Kmeans algo but I do not know during compile time the size of the dataset aka the number of features.

I see that the vector type length is supposed to be a const and thus trying to pass as an argument will not work.

```
class Data
{ 
    public string ID{ get; set; }

    [VectorType(5)] //I do not know the if the data will contain 5 or more features
    public float[] Features { get; set; }   
}
```

To be used:

```
InputData row = new InputData { AssetID = Data[0, i + 1].ToString(), Features = features };

var context = new MLContext();
var DataView = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dataArray);
string featuresColumnName = "Features";
var pipeline=context.Transforms.Concatenate(featuresColumnName,"Features")             .Append(context.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, clustersCount: NumberClusters));

var model = pipeline.Fit(DataView);
```

Comment: Is your number of Features a fixed number at runtime, or a jagged array? ML.NET algorithms(trainers) work with fixed size float vectors.

Comment: Yeah at runtime I know the dimension but it seems that the Schema in DataView uses a const type and thus is evaluated at compile time. It is strange that we need to know the size of the vectors and hard-code it, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimension of the vector is fixed, you can work around at runtime:

```
 private class SampleTemperatureDataVector
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public float[] Temperature { get; set; }
    }
```

notice this type has not annotations. You can create SchemaDefinition from it, than modify that schema. The initial SchemaDefinition will have the `IsKnownSize` property set to `false`. After the modification the `Size` will be set to the dimension you set it, 3 in this case.

```
        var data2 = new SampleTemperatureDataVector[]
        {
            new SampleTemperatureDataVector
            {
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow, 
                Temperature = new float[] {1.2f, 3.4f, 5.6f}
            },
             new SampleTemperatureDataVector
            {
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Temperature = new float[] {1.2f, 3.4f, 5.6f}
            },
        };

        int featureDimension = 3;
        var autoSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(SampleTemperatureDataVector));
        var featureColumn = autoSchema[1];
        var itemType = ((VectorDataViewType)featureColumn.ColumnType).ItemType;
        featureColumn.ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(itemType, featureDimension);

        IDataView data3 = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data2, autoSchema);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. Which version of ML.NET are you using ?

Comment: I was using 1.0. This is now under the ML.NET samples as well: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/DataOperations/LoadFromEnumerable.cs